# CSS values using HTML5 data attribute

Tags: html, css, attributes, custom-data-attribute

```
width: attr(data-width);
```

I want to know if there's any way it's possible to set a css value using HTML5's `data-` attribute the same way that you can set css `content`. Currently it doesn't work.

---

HTML

```
<div data-width="600px"></div>
```

CSS

```
div { width: attr(data-width) }
```

Comment: AFAIK you can’t using just CSS. It’s fully possible using javascript though.

Comment: Semantically this is a bad idea because it breaks separation of mark-up and layout.

Comment: You need to find a better example because the solution to your problem above is using <div style="width: 600px;"></div> instead of <div data-width="600px"></div>. At the moment I can only imagine your question being interesting regarding attribute selectors: http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

Comment: I had the same problem as well. I am doing some transition and animation work. The data-* attributes can be used to store the initial properties of an element. I thought I could access those stored values with CSS but it seems it can only be done with JS.

Comment: Yes and it was called HTML 1.0. Years later people figured out that mixing document structure and presentation was a bad idea and separated them into two parts: HTML and CSS. It's not too hard to imagine that re-combining them again is a bad idea.

Comment: Better example, say your CSS looks more like this `div::after { width: attr(data-width) }`. You want to modify the value with JS, but you can't (easily) modify pseudo elements, so reading from a data-* property would be ideal.

Comment: you can add inline style with css variable and then use the var from your style.  you can see it [here](https://css-tricks.com/css-attr-function-got-nothin-custom-properties/#article-header-id-0)

Comment: LOOK (https://css-tricks.com/css-attr-function-got-nothin-custom-properties/)

Comment: @T.Junghans And then you'll get into trouble with your CSP, unless of course you add unsafe-inline, defeating the whole purpose of the CSP. And providing a hash for your CSP would only work if it's a fixed value. And a nonce doesn't work here.

Sidenote: Of course if you can dynamically change the style attribute, you can also dynamically create a style tag with it's dynamically created rules on which you can apply a nonce.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

There is, indeed, prevision for such feature, look http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr-notation

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/wp7Wc/4/) should work like what you need, but will not for now.

Unfortunately, it's still a draft, and isn't fully implemented on major browsers.

It does work for `content` on pseudo-elements, though.

Comment: is this css syntax `content: attr(data-content);` cross browser? does it work until IE8?

Comment: Update - this is now a usable feature in browsers.

Comment: @CaptainHypertext According to `caniuse.com`, the function is still widely unsupported (except for strings in the content attribute of pseudo-elements).  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-attr

Comment: @Zeus Zdravkov: What kind of logic is that? The whole *point* of this answer is that the code doesn't work - because it's not supported in the first place. How is that the answer's fault?

Answer (score 12):

You can create with javascript some css-`rules`, which you can later use in your styles: **http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/vKbda/**

```
var addRule = (function (sheet) {
    if(!sheet) return;
    return function (selector, styles) {
        if (sheet.insertRule) return sheet.insertRule(selector + " {" + styles + "}", sheet.cssRules.length);
        if (sheet.addRule) return sheet.addRule(selector, styles);
    }
}(document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1]));

var i = 101;
while (i--) {
    addRule("[data-width='" + i + "%']", "width:" + i + "%");
}
```

This creates 100 pseudo-selectors like this:

```
[data-width='1%'] { width: 1%; }
[data-width='2%'] { width: 2%; }
[data-width='3%'] { width: 3%; }
...
[data-width='100%'] { width: 100%; }
```

Note: This is a bit offtopic, and not really what you (or someone) wants, but maybe helpful.

Answer (score 8):

As of today, you can read some values from HTML5 `data` attributes in CSS3 declarations. In [CaioToOn's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/wp7Wc/4/) the CSS code can use the `data` properties for setting the `content`.

Unfortunately it is not working for the `width` and `height` (tested in Google Chrome 35, Mozilla Firefox 30 & Internet Explorer 11).

But there is a [CSS3 attr() Polyfill](http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/Dsdkr) from Fabrice Weinberg which provides support for `data-width` and `data-height`. You can find the GitHub repo to it here: [cssattr.js](https://github.com/FWeinb/cssattr.js).