# CSS rule from data-* attribute

Tags: css, html, attributes

Say I have a portion of my HTML file that looks like this:

```
<div data-w="20px">
    <p>this is some text this is some text this is some text</p>
</div>
```

And the `<div>`'s width should equal `data-w`, as shown below.

```
div { width:[data-w]; }
```

I know I can use `[attribute]` as a selector, but honestly, this is not an alternative:

```
div[data-w=1px]{ width:1px; }
div[data-w=2px]{ width:1px; }
div[data-w=3px]{ width:1px; }
div[data-w=4px]{ width:1px; }
div[data-w=5px]{ width:1px; }
div[data-w=1px]{ width:1px; }
div[data-w=1px]{ width:1px; }
        (...)
```

Ideas?

### Edit

I found a [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523197/css-values-using-html5-data-attribute?rq=1)

Comment: Do you want `<div data-w="20px">` to be `20px`? If yes than there's no way you can do it without the attribute selector

Comment: @Mr.Alien yes, but I might make another `<div>` with `data-w`=another value.

Comment: Ya so why you don't want to go for attribute selector? any specific reason?

Comment: There's [`width: attr(data-w px)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/attr), but it's still experimental. *However* , it seems to me that this would break the separation between content and presentation.

Comment: Because it's a numeric value, that can go from 0 to some value, and I need a simpler way of doing so without a bunch of selectors.

Comment: If you don't want to make for each value a selector in css then the only way is to loop through all elements with the data-* attribute and do something depending on the value. That would be for sure in javascript. CSS is not made for such stuff.

Comment: If you can generate HTML with `data-w="20px"` why don't you generate HTML with `style="width:20px;"`?

Comment: @Tom I feared someone would ask that. That is because I don't want the HTML to override my CSS, rather than having the CSS change the HTML, according to the HTML.

Comment: The sample code describing the goal does not match the verbal description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use jQuery I suppose.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqJqW/1)**.

```
$("div").each(function() {
    var w = $(this).data("w");
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.width(w);
});​
```

As said in the comments, this is impossible to do in mere CSS.

Comment: Accepted, since it's not experimental and won't mess up.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, because you are hardcoding the width, it would be better to use:

```
<div style="width:20px">
    <p>this is some text this is some text this is some text</p>
</div>
```