# Picking and calling original css with data() and attr() works in Firefox, but not in Opera and Chrome?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, jquery-data, jquery-attributes

I want to be able to reset draggable div to it's original position after dragging (jquery ui `draggable()`) on some event in jquery. I did this:

```
$('#nav').draggable();

$('#nav').data({'x': $("#nav").css('left'), 'y': $("#nav").css('top')});

$("#c").click(function () {
    $('#nav').animate({'left': parseInt($("#nav").data('x')) - 15, 'top': parseInt($("#nav").data('y')) - 14}, {duration : 500});
});
```

and it works even in older Firefox but not in newest Opera and Chrome. I tried to replace data() with attr() and it's still the same.

How can this be achieved in a more cross-browser manner?

**edit**: here is this code in action: **http://jsfiddle.net/MVCA6/**

Comment: If possible prepare jsfiddle for it.So that we can lookup through it

Comment: here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MVCA6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chrome i HAve seen result using

```
console.log($("#nav").data('x'));
```

It return `auto`;

In mozilla it gives

```
447px
```

Possibly this may be the reason why it is not working in chrome.But if you assign left and top property in #nav  in css as

```
left:447px;top:352px
```

It works fine. 
[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6HGSH/)

For more detail you can also take help from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523197/css-values-using-html5-data-attribute)

Comment: The problem is I really need to position this element with bottom and right, because it should be in the bottom-right corner of the fluid page, but on the exact same place relative to it's parent (fluid footer), which is why I don't use `position:fixed`, `left:90%` etc. Is there any workaround possible?

Comment: am not able to understand this line of your comment "exact same place relative to it's parent". which place relative to parent,or it should be always bottom-left corner of a page

Comment: my fluid footer is defined with `left:150px; right:150px`, not with percentages, but I guess you are right. I'm being too picky. I'll just use the fixed position with % and treat the element independently. I'll probably switch the footer to percentages anyway. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that jQuery UI Draggable uses the `top` and `left` properties to move elements around, whereas you're setting the red boxes position using `bottom` and `right`;

Adding `console.log($('#nav').data())` to the click event you'll see your properties `x` and `y` are both set to `auto`.

To solve this you'll need to update your CSS to position the red box using `top` and `left`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MVCA6/1/

**As a side note:** Proper indentation of code can help wonders when it comes to debugging issues.

Comment: Thing is I need to use bottom and right, or to do some workaround. I explained why in the reply to Roshan jha. Is there a possible solution, or `left:90%` etc is really the only way to go?

Comment: no answer needed. even if there is a workaround, it's probably better to do a minor css tweaking. Thanks for the help.