# How to get access to css selector result inside the brackets?

Tags: html, css, sass

Suppose you have 10 HTML elements with ids 1 to 9; element 1 has `id="1"`, etc. This is what I want to do. "(IdNumber)" is not in syntax and used for only illustration:

```
// for all elements
 #(IdNumber) {width: (IdNumber)%;}
```

So the end result should make the width of each element equal to its id; first element's width is 1%, etc. I want to use an unspecified CSS selector's result, like here it is the id string, inside the brackets as a value.

Comment: I assume the elements and Ids are generated somehow (js or server code)? Can that generation include an inline style reusing the variable for the Id and width?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523197/css-values-using-html5-data-attribute

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this:

```
@for $w from 1 through 9 {
  ##{$w} {
    width: unquote('#{$w}%');
  } 
}
```

But I would strongly encourage to also prefix your ids with some character because while pure numeric ids are [allowed in html5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), this was not so for html4 and it generally can lead to problems because purely numeric id can't be distinguished from number.

Answer (score 0):

(Using LESS) you can achieve this by the following:
EG HTML:

```
<div id="MyDiv">
  <div id="MyDiv1"></div>
   <div id="MyDiv2"></div>
</div>
```

LESS:

```
#MyDiv{
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  border:red 1px solid;
  #MyDiv1{
    width: 10%;
    height:20px;
    border:red 1px solid;
  }
}
.setWidth{
  width: 20%;
}
#MyDiv2{
  .setWidth;  
  height:30px;
  border:red 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selector on css but you should write style for each id separately, for eaxmple :

Html :

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
```

Css :

```
<style>
    div {
        background-color: blueviolet;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        height: 30px
    }
     [id="1"] {
         width: 1%;

     }
    [id="2"] {
        width: 2%;
    }
    [id="3"] {
        width: 3%;
    }
    [id="4"] {
        width: 4%;
    }
</style>
```

I hope it's usefull .

Comment: I now how to do it seperate. But I want to do it together.